# Using onConfigurationChanged in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation, onconfigurationchanged

I have this code in a fragment

```
public class TestOne extends Fragment {

    View view = null;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.testone, null); 

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Rotate fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCreate Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testone, null); 

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCreateView fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return view; 
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is that, when I rotate the phone, I don't want the methods to be executed again. But I want to call again the xml layout, to load the layout-land folder's xml.

This code does not give any error, just does not work and do not understand the reason ..

I'm really interested in doing it using onConfiguratonChanged

I appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards

Comment: the methods in your `FragmentActivity`

Comment: there are methods that should be in the fragment

Comment: And why should it work? In the `onConfigurationChanged` you simply inflate a layout and assign it to one of the fields of the `Activity`. I would advise you to use `setRetainInstance(true)` instead of the `onConfigurationChanged` way. As a manual solution I guess you could always remove all views from `getView()` and reattach the newly inflated layout.

Comment: I've searched but can not find any example showing how to use setRetainInstance (true). It is advisable to use it?

Comment: Please specifically describe how it fails. "just does not work" is not very clear.

Comment: Instead of using `onConfigurationChanged` you would set `setRetainInstance()` in the `onCreate()` method of the `Fragment`. This way the fragment instance will be kept across a configuration change, but the lifecycle methods will still be called in a slightly different order (so you would need to make some changes to them). If you just want to keep some data from being recreated then use a non UI fragment with `setRetainInstance()` to keep the data and let the fragment above be recreated(getting the data from that non UI fragment).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In `onCreateView` create `FrameLayout` - this is the container for you `fragmenView`. Then create your `R.layout.testone` and add it to `frameLayout`.

In `onConfigurationChanged` clear `FrameLayout`, create `R.layout.testone` again and add it to `frameLayout`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testone, null);
    frameLayout .addView(view);
    return frameLayout; 
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    frameLayout. removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testone, null);
    frameLayout .addView(view);
}
```

Now all will work as you want!

Comment: it have lot of problem