# Change Fragment layout on orientation change from layout and layout-land

Tags: android, layout, orientation, fragment

I'he tried  for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116602/using-onconfigurationchanged-in-a-fragment) answer
but its disappears my view on change orientation.

thanks for help

Comment: Why do u want to load another layout in landscape mode?

Comment: @Dipu because my background image is different for both layout.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a Fragment class, call it from Activity.Then create layout-land folder,put same layout file in both layout and layout-land folder.Now you can use background according to your requirement for portrait and landscape mode.
In Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity" >
```

You don't need to use onConfigurationChanged() for this operation,this will automatically call xml from layout in portrait mode and from layout-land in landscape mode.